# Mediatek-res.apk causing bootloop

Tags: boot, boot-loop, unbricking, bootloader

Right, so I've been an absolute idiot and I uninstalled mediatek-res.apk. I was probably very tired and I was stupid enough to forget to make a backup in recovery. The phone is a Chinese clone (Jiake JK3) and I can't find any stock firmware on the internet. It's now stuck in bootloop, so somehow I need to restore mediatek-res.apk. I can get adb access with root when I'm in recovery. I've tried pushing it to /system/framework with the correct permissions, but that hasn't worked. The log (when I boot up) says:

```
D/PackageManager( 1699): scan package: /system/framework/mediatek-res.apk , start at: 66650ms.

D/asset   ( 1699): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
```

and

```
I/PackageManager( 1699): /system/framework/mediatek-res.apk changed; collecting certs

D/dalvikvm( 1699): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1976K (15855), 34% free 4069K/6124K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 19ms
```

and

```
E/PackageManager( 1699): Package com.mediatek has no signatures that match those in shared user android.uid.system; ignoring!

W/PackageManager( 1699): Signature mismatch for shared user : SharedUserSetting{41de1470 android.uid.system/1000}
```

I have no idea what any of this means but I'm a fairly capable user so if someone could let me know what it means that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature mismatch indicates that the package you've installed (the `mediatek-res.apk`) isn't from the same source as the rest of the OS. It's from a different ROM, probably one made for a different device, by a different OEM. You need to find the APK file that matches the rest of your ROM, from the same device as yours.

Comment: Would turning off Signature Verification in the Recovery make any difference at all? If the OP has the ROM zip on their device/PC then they could pull out the apk probably anyway. Or dirty flash the ROM over itself..? Also worth noting: ALWAYS ALWAYS make a [tag:nandroid] backup before deleting anything from `/system` or flashing zip files at all!

Comment: I don't think so, as it's not the recovery that's checking the signature, it's Android itself.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with the Android bootloader. I might have managed to recover the original APK, because when I tried a new apk it boots to the lock screen and works for a second, then displays a force close message for Google Play Services and reboots. I've been trying to contact other people with the device from various Android forums so they can upload their firmware.